# Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @COUNT_P INT
DECLARE @COUNT_S INT


SELECT MEMBNO, 
CASE 
WHEN TYPCOD = 'P' THEN @COUNT_P = @COUNT_P + 1
END AS C_P,
CASE 
WHEN TYPCOD = 'S' THEN @COUNT_S = @COUNT_S + 1 
END AS C_S
FROM #TEMP2
GROUP BY TYPCOD
```

The error that I am getting is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MEMBNO, 
SUM(CASE 
WHEN TYPCOD = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) AS C_P,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN TYPCOD = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_S
FROM #TEMP2
GROUP BY MEMBNO
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the intention of the OP's code (but this is at least syntactically correct).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment values like that in SQL Server.  A `SELECT` either returns values or sets variables, but not both.

```
DECLARE @COUNT_P INT;
DECLARE @COUNT_S INT;
```

If you want to set the total number for the two types, then:

```
select @count_p = sum(case when typecode = 'P' then 1 else 0 end),
       @count_s = sum(case when typecode = 'S' then 1 else 0 end)
from #TEMP2;
```

Comment: I did as u said and I get this error - A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations. Can you help me with this

Comment: @shailuk . . . Do you get that error with this code?